# prove that $m(\emptyset) = 0$ where $m$ is countably additive over disjoint collection of sets of $\mathscr{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove that if $A \in \mathscr{A}$, where $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra for which $m(A) < \infty$, then $m(\emptyset) = 0$.

This is my approach.

Notice that $A \cup \emptyset = A$ and $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$. Then using the countably additive property, I have:
$$m(A \cup \emptyset = A)  = m(A) \Rightarrow m(A) + m(\emptyset) = m(A) \Rightarrow m(\emptyset) = 0$$
Is this approach correct.

Comment: Yup. Looks good.

Comment: Yes, countable additivity implies binary additivity (over disjoint sets).

Comment: Your approach is correct but do note why $m(A)<\infty$ is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Writing this so that this question can be marked answered.*

Your approach is correct, because $(A, \emptyset)$ is a disjoint partition of $A$ and you can apply countable additivity as you did.